# WCF Web Service Call Using SOAP 1.1

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services

I'm attempting to call a web service from a VB .NET 3.5 Win Forms application. I have been able to create a Service Reference but when I call the web service I receive the SOAP fault:

```
A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint.
```

The web service uses username and password authentication with a certificate. I also need to connect to different URLs depending on the environment (development or production). For these reasons I was attempting to use a WSHttpBinding created in code. However, it appears that type of binding assumes SOAP 1.2. I've been told by the author of the web service that they are unable to support SOAP 1.2.

Is there a way, either with the WSHttpBinding or a CustomBinding in code, to consume a web service that only supports SOAP 1.1 using a WCF Service Reference?

```
Dim binding As New System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding

binding.Security.Mode = ServiceModel.SecurityMode.Transport
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic

Dim service As New ServiceReference.ServiceClient(binding, New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(baseUrl))

service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = serviceUsername
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = servicePassword
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: BasicHttpBinding supports SOAP 1.1.  WsHttpBinding is for 1.2.

Comment: That's true, but when using a BasicHttpBinding we were running into a different error because the username and password were not being sent in the http header. We ended up using a BasicHttpBinding but had to also modify the header to include the username and password.